# How can I call 'BeginPlay' on 'UDataAsset' ? (unreal)

Tags: unreal-engine4

I made UDataAsset.
And I want to call BeginPlay function on UDataAsset.
I just put BeginPlay function on UDataAsset script just like Actor does.
But it didn't work.
How can I do this?

```
UCLASS()
class GAME_API UCData : public UDataAsset
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
        
public:
    void BeginPlay(class ACharacter* InCharacter);
}
```

This didn't work for me...
Am I missing something?
Please help me..

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that data assets have single instances. This means if you set multiple things (components, actors etc...) to refernce the same data asset - they'll all be referencing the same one in memory. This may lead to unintended consequences with a BeginPlay style function, since you'll likely be calling it more than once.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, [UDataAsset](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/UDataAsset/) inherits from [UObject](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/UObject/); UObject doesn't include a function for BeginPlay, so you won't get the behaviour you would expect if the data asset inherited from [AActor](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/).

If there is an owner for the data asset, they can provide that call into your version of BeginPlay.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. UDataAsset can't have beginPlay so I called BeginPlay on DataAsset from the other component.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30751470)

Comment: I post answer to complete answers to the question. I found the solution...